# Is it possible to separate the Xbox One & PC Skype accounts?

Tags: xbox-one, skype

I log into my Xbox One and it automatically logs me into my skype account with the same email address as my profile, e.g. `myBoxName@hotmail.com`.

However I'd like to use this Skype account on my PC, and use a different Skype account to associate with my profile on the Xbox One.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I assume Xbox One will use your Microsoft account in Skype... Can you log out from Skype? There should be a sign out button at the bottom right when you click your avatar in the top right in home view.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to sign out of Skype, hence, there is no way to sign in with a different account. See [this MS Support page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/apps/skype-faq#e1374fff207544cd8c7c78620b2745f3) for the source information.

What you can do is set Skype on your main account to be silent, set it to being invisible and disable notifications. Then sign in on your one using the profile you have associated your main Skype activity with. As it is an MS account, you can use it without any problem. Now, if you assign the second profile to your family on the One, it can benefit from your Gold subscription and you will be able to use Skype without much trouble.